# How to avoid for loop in R when altering a column

Tags: r, performance, loops, for-loop, vector

I'm working with a data frame that looks very similar to the below:

[Image here, unfortunately don't have enough reputation yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6CHA.png)

This is a 600,000 row data frame. What I want to do is for every repeated instance within the same date, I'd like to divide the cost by total number of repeated instances. I would also like to consider only those falling under the "Sales" tactic.

So for example, in 1/1/16, there are 2 "Help Packages" that are also under the "Sales" tactic. Because there are 2 instances within the same date, I'd like to divide the cost of each by 2 (so the cost would come out as $5 for each).

This is the code I have:

```
for(i in 1:length(dfExample$Date)){
  if(dfExample$Tactic) == "Sales"){
    list = agrep(dfExample$Package[i], dfExample$Package)
    for(i in list){
      date_repeats = agrep(i, dfExample$Date)
      dfExample$Cost[date_repeats] = dfExample$Package[i]/length(date_repeats)
      }
  }
}
```

It is incredibly inefficient and slow. I know there's got to be a better way to achieve this. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: No one wants an image of data. Share your data with `dput(droplevels(head(your_data)))`. It will be copy/pasteable and preserve column classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ave()` can give a solution without additional packages:

```
with(dfExample, Cost / ave(Cost, Date, Package, Tactic, FUN=length))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
dfExample %>%
    group_by(Date, Package, Tactic) %>%
    mutate(Cost = Cost / n())
```

I'm a little unclear what you mean by "instance". This (pretty clearly) groups by Date, Package, and Tactic, and so will consider each unique combination of those columns as a grouper. If you don't include `Tactic` in the definition of an "instance", then you can remove it to group only by Date and Package.